# Передача результата в параметр функции

Tags: python

Как передать функции в качестве второго параметра результат другой функции?

Answer (score 2):

[Как пример можно сделать так](https://onlinegdb.com/HJvg5kJtI):

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

def out(x):
    print(x);

out(add(2, 2))
```

Подробнее о работе с функциями можно почитать [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html).